# Is there a nonstandard characterization of Lipschitz continuity?

Tags: metric-spaces, nonstandard-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be Lipschitz continuous with finite constant $L$.
Then
$$
|f(x) - f(y) \le L |x-y|, \tag{1}
$$
and, by direct transfer, this property holds for $^*\!f$.
For continuity, there is the infinitesimal characterization
$$
x \approx y \to f(x) \approx f(y). \tag{2}
$$

I'm wondering if there exists an infinitesimal characterization of (1).
I ask because (1) lacks the infinitesimal feeling that (2) gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the definition you give is not for continuity (of standard functions), but for *uniform* continuity. $f(x) = x^2$, for example, doesn't satisfy that property: e.g. take $x = H+1/H$ and $y = H$, where $H$ is a transfinite number.

I'm not entirely sure there's a need for an "infinitesimal" version of Lipschitz continuity, since it is already free from the usual annoyances of standard analysis, but here goes.

For any positive constant $\delta$, you can restrict the standard definition to require that inequality only for $|x - y| < \delta$. For a a nonstandard version, it should be enough to prove the inequality only for $x \approx y$.

I assert the following:

> A standard function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if $(f(x) - f(y))/(x-y)$ is limited for all $x,y$ with $x \approx y$ and $x \neq y$.

(equivalently, you could replace $x \approx y$ with "$x-y$ limited", or even remove that condition entirely).

**Proof:** $(\Rightarrow)$ is straightforward. To prove $(\Leftarrow)$, suppose that $q(x,y) = (f(x) - f(y))/(x-y)$ is limited for all $x,y$ with $x \approx y$, $x \neq y$. Then $f$ is continuous.

Now let $x<y$ be any nonstandard numbers, and let $x = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = y$ be a (hyperfinite) sequence such that $x_i \approx x_{i+1}$. The set of values $|q(x_{i+1}, x_i)|$ is hyperfinite (and internal), and thus has a maximum value $M$, which is limited. Thus $|f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)| \leq M |x_{i+1} - x_i|$, and it follows that $|q(x,y)| \leq M$.

Thus, $q(x,y)$ is limited for all $x \neq y$.

Let $H$ be positive transfinite, and $\epsilon$ be positive infinitesimal. $|q(x,y)|$ is a continuous function on the (internally) closed and bounded set $|x| \leq H \wedge |x-y| \in [\epsilon, H]$, and thus attains a maximum value $M$, which is limited. Let $L$ be any standard number larger than $M$.

We now have

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x-y| $$

for every standard $x,y$, and therefore $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Just to dot the i's: the infinitesimal definition does give the usual notion of continuity (rather than uniform continuity) if $x$ is restricted to be real (rather than arbitrary hyperreal).  Namely $f$ is continuous at $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only of $x\approx y$ implies $f^*(x)\approx f^*(y)$ where $f^*$ is the natural extension of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the answer is Yes, but morally, No.

The Lipschitz condition with exponent $\alpha  < 1$ has very little content for infinitesimally close (bounded) $x,y$.  Any differentiable function on a bounded set will satisfy $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|^\alpha$ for infinitesimally near points, and an arbitrary value of $L$.  Thus, it is a large-scale constraint on the function and there is no way to localize the condition to small neighborhoods.

For $\alpha > 1$ there are no locally nonconstant functions satisfying the condition.  Any constraints created by the Lipschitz condition are large-scale, controlling the variation of function values on separated components of the domain. Within components it is constant.

For $\alpha=1$, the inequality (for any metric space where distance can be estimated arbitrarily closely by paths of "short jumps") is equivalent, with the same constant $L$, to its restriction to infinitesimally close $x$ and $y$, with a one line proof "apply triangle inequality to an estimating path".  So the restatement will look the same as the original with unnecessary extra words added, like *infinitely close* and *standard*.

Related Q&A at [$|f(x)-f(y)|\le(x-y)^2$ without gaplessness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334934/fx-fy-lex-y2-without-gaplessness)